# Updating the next line in a specific column in pandas dataframe depending on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas dataframe and i would like to update my column ' signal' depending on a condition.

While iterating over the column if the value is' 1 ' or '-1' and the next row has the same number, the second '1' or '-1' must be updated to 0.
In the end there should not be two consecutive 1 or -1.

I am trying this code and got no changes.

```
for i in df['signal'].iteritems(): 
    if i == 1 :
        while next() == 1:
            i=0
    elif i == -1:
        while next() == -1:
            i=0
```

Comment: What output do you expect when there are 3 consecutive 1's? For example, what should be the result if your column 'signal' contains values [1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1 , 1] ?

Comment: i only should have result like this [1,0,0,1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,0] 'as example' because this column willl help me later to set some other various calcul on other column. when i have two consecutif 1 or -1 the other column can't do my real calculation.

Comment: @gpweb never have consecutif 1 or -1, so will never have 3 consecutive as you said. I don't know i am explaining well my problem but the goal is to never repeat the 1 value or -1 until it is breaked by 0. which means i am allowed to have consecutive 0 in my column. Could you help on this please?

Comment: You should provide an example of an input (the content of df['signal']) and the output that you expect, because it is really not clear.

Comment: here my exemple; signal is the column i have and i added a column' expected_signal' for you just to explain what my first signal should really contains:

Comment: i am trying to get you data as my output but keep having the incorrect format to show you :

Comment: the content of isgnal is = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0 ].

my expected signal is [1.0, 0.0, .0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0 ].

and signal is not a list but a column in dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column in the dataframe with the data shifted by 1 and a new column for the output. If, on a row, the original signal and the shifted one  are equal, it means that, for example, there are two consecutive 1's (and you are on the row of the second). So you put 0 in the output column. Otherwise you copy the original value.

You could start with this code (it seems it works on the data you provided in the comments, but you should check on other examples too):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 1.0 ])
df['shifted'] = df.shift(1) #add the column with shifted values
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[0] if x.signal != x.shifted else 0, axis=1)
```